# Have JS Run Alert Box Upon success submission

Tags: php, javascript

**PHP Script**
The php script that is executed once the form is filled out:

```
   <?php    
    $connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Connect Submit at this time.");
        mysql_select_db($db);

        ## Escape bad input including '/', '"', etc
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(!empty($_POST['InterestedEmail']))
            $subscriberEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InterestedEmail']);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(!empty($_POST['InterestedBrowser']))
            $subscriberBrowser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InterestedBrowser']);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        ## check for nmll values, if all are set, INSERT
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query="INSERT INTO launching(lauEmail, lauBrowser) 
        values('$subscriberEmail', '$subscriberBrowser')";
        mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
            #HERE
        }

        ?>
```

How do I get PHP to run this JS code: `window.alert('Submitted. Thank you.')` once the script reaches `#HERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could end the PHP and restart it and just put the JS in there, or if you want to embed it right there in the PHP where you have #here then how about echo/print it:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "window.alert('Submitted. Thank you.')";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing server-side and client-side scripting. PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. There's no way to have PHP display an alert or run any JS code, the client/browser must do this. While you can output a simple JS snippet that will achieve this, you're forcing the user to reload the page (which will likely either contain the form they just filled out, which is confusing, or a blank page with a single alert).

A much more intuitive and user-friendly approach is to use AJAX to prevent reloading the page for the form submission. Here is a simple example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Send an AJAX request to the server
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://www.example', // Change this to your URL
  data: { submit: 'true', InterestedEmail: 'something', InterestedBrowser: 'something' }, // Fetch the data from the <input> elements here
  success:function(data){
    if( data.success) {
        window.alert('Submitted. Thank you.');
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

Then, modify your PHP script to send some sort of response (I'm using JSON):

```
if( isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    ...
    echo json_encode( array( 'success' => true));
    exit; 
}
```

This example is incomplete, however, as you'll need to send a JSON encoded response for any data that is returned to via AJAX.

Comment: I think this is the more elegant solution. But also the tougher to implement.